# Change of variables - Wasserstein distance

Tags: change-of-variable, optimal-transport, wasserstein

[image]

My question is how exactly the change of variable formula is applied in the second row of the equation?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure

Comment: @Tobsn thanks. Can you give me a hint no how to apply the formula to this case?

Comment: 'apply' is a big word here. I don't really see your confusion. It's just plugging in the definition of $\gamma$.